# How can I show 4 products in each row in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Well I am using a custom theme for woocomerce! Currently I am using the below code to fetch the products!  It currently displays 5 products in a row.

I want to display 4 products in each row? How can I do that?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
      <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the number of posts per page before calling the loop. Try this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=4'); ?>
    <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Update**

Seems that this can be done using CSS. So if you need to list 4 product per row, then make this change in your stlye.css at line number 2980.

```
.container .products li {width: 19%!important;}
```

to

```
.container .products li {width: 23%!important;}
```

**Update1**

This is not possible only with css. You need to wrap your divs around the li tags. Change your code so that it `adds div after each` 4 li tags. So you need to wrap 4 li tags in a div. This is the way we can make things look the way you want. Another option will be to add a `height or min-height` for each li tags.

Hope this helps you

Comment: @DebakantMohanty can you make wp_debug true and check for the errors

Comment: yeah I defined wp_debug true, but I can't see any error here and one more thing I do not want to show 4 products per page I just wanted to show 20 products per page and 4 products per row! Hope that is clear!

Comment: @DebakantMohanty sorry I misunderstood your request. Do you have an url I can check with. Is the above code listing 5 products per page ? If you remove the query_posts is it working ?

Comment: Alright, here is my site url: http://wp.raddyx.in/Demo/?product_cat=nokia-mobiles

I have removed the query_posts and now irs listing all my products, but what I need is the 5th product should start with a new row!

Comment: @DebakantMohanty this is only showing one row with 5 products right? So how do you list the 20 products?

Comment: I am sorry, My development partner has removed some of the products from that category, I just readded some test products, Currently I hav e 8 products total! Please check now

Comment: so you just increased the width of the li, but you still must be seeing the design break still appears there!!, This is what I am seeing from the beginning!

Comment: @DebakantMohanty wordpress has nothing to do with that. You need to adjust your css accordingly to make the products 4 in a row. Please make neccessary changes in other styles so that it looks good. Also what was the design break there? It seems to be Ok for me. Can you tell me what is the design issue. I can solve that for you if possible

Comment: There you can see the 5th product way right and the 6th -8th in another row!

Comment: @DebakantMohanty I am checking in chrome . THis is my screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/08e22kt152. This seems ok to be me. Can you clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: @DebakantMohanty is this a responsive site ??

Comment: oh yes its a responsive theme, and regarding the screen shot it looks good in yours but not here in my screen!! Here is my screenshot http://www.screencast.com/users/Debakant/folders/Default/media/8454cb53-6f05-4a5d-a938-02b64866db14

Comment: Change the sorting you will see the difference!'

Comment: @DebakantMohanty please check my edit. You need to make changes in your code